# Phalcon: different behavior of $di->get and arrayAccess methods

Tags: phalcon

Example:

```
$di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault\CLI();
for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->id = $i;
    $di->set('obj', $obj);
    var_dump($di->get('obj')->id); // same as $i
    //$di->getService('obj')->resolve(); // this trick doesn't help too
    var_dump($di['obj']->id); // always 1
}
```

We use arrayAccess in our project to get di keys and we want to have the ability to replace services in di.

Is it normal behavior of get and arrayAccess methods?

How can we replace services in di in case of arrayAccess?

Answer (score 0):

`offsetGet()` is equivalent to `DI::getShared()`

So, if you modify the code like this:

`-var_dump($di->get('obj')->id);
+var_dump($di->getShared('obj')->id);`

you will have 1 printed in both cases.

Looks like there is a bug that `unset($di['obj'])` does not kill the shared instance nor `$di['obj']` updates the object but I guess you'd better file a bug report for that :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Issue on github: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2867